# HTML form in tables or not

Tags: html, css, forms, tablelayout

Before anyone close this question or complain... I've been looking all over StackOverFlow site but couldn't find anything straight foward about tables and forms.

I have a form which has at least 20 to 35 labels and text boxes, in different categories. So to start using CSS for each element would be too much.

For some reason, I'm feeling like using tables to align all the fields with their respective labels, since some labels will be larger than others ***(i.e. 'First Name' is a larger word than 'Age')***, and so the layout would be distorted. And I can't start applying css for each label and text box (circa 20 each... that's 40 individual css rules).

Unless someone can give me some techniques, I'll be greatful.

I know CSS is good for forms but what about the very big forms?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a table

Comment: 20 textboxes and 35 lables is not **big** form. feel free to use tables or css. use technology, you are familiar with.

Comment: Waiting for someone to link to http://giveupandusetables.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you use the cascade to your advantage, there is nothing wrong with CSS for forms.

In fact, I recommend it over using `table`.

Just set up some base rules...

```
input {
   padding: 3px;
   float: right;
}
```

Then handle the exceptions to your rules...

```
input#age {
   float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms are not tabular data, simple forms just superficially look like they are.

CSS is just fine for long forms. Have styles for most data. Then more specific styles for short bits of data and/or long bits of data, and so on. Don't style everything individually.

Comment: Is there a sane non-table way to dynamically resize columns depending on how much text they contain, though? I'm not aware of one.

Comment: There are the various values for `display` that makes things display like bits of tables, but for the most part setting some sane widths, and a light dusting of `float` and `clear` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

try using UL and LI instead of table, such as explained in the following article [Click to see article](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/form-elements-design-using-css-and-list.html)

It provides the CSS too.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need 40 individual CSS rules. You could have one rule for all the labels, and one for all text boxes.

BUT - having said that - this sort of layout, where you have two columns of stuff, and you want all the stuff in column 1 (the labels in this example) aligned with each other, and all the stuff in col 2 (the text boxes) aligned with each other, while keeping the rows aligned - well that's exactly the sort of thing that the the good ol' table excels at.

I am a big advocate of CSS, and I believe that *abuse* of tables (to layout a page for example) is evil, evil, evil - but I would definitely go with tables on this one.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, it's all about preference and functionality. My personal preference are divs/CSS.  The cascading nature of CSS, and cleanliness of the code, etc..

But hey, if you like tables - shout it from a rooftop!

Comment: Oddly enough, you don't need jQuery (a library built around a CSS selector engine) to apply CSS to all labels (`label {}`) or inputs (`input {}`). And don't shout about liking to use tables for non-tabular data, its like confessing to enjoying … (well, something unsavoury).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/).

As far as I can see, it will achieve the layout you need and all you have to do is add classes and single line of JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create good, accessible forms using CSS without too many CSS rules (for the alignment part, anyway).  You basically just need to set the width of all the labels -- with one rule -- and define how they interact with the input elements.  There a nice article at http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/forms/ (just the first one I found, I'm sure there are many others).

Answer (score -1):

For a form IMO i'd rather use a table its cleaner. Use CSS for your websites layout. But again thats my opinion...

Comment: Also something i forgot to mention which right after I posted someone else posted (or just before i posted?) you can use the <ul> and <li> to do this also